# Sending data via post without using apache classes

Tags: android

I want to send data to a php server without using `http classes` if this is possible; ie the `org.apache.http` package.

My code until now

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class serverHandler extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {


    Context context;
    ByteArrayOutputStream content;

    public serverHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream input = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();

            byte buff[] = new byte[4096];
            content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(buff)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button

                content.write(buff,0,count);
                total += count;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {

                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return new String(content.toByteArray());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String country = "No Country";

        if(result.length()==0){
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        try{

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONObject address = data.getJSONObject("address");
            country = address.getString("country");


        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context,country,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I know that sending `POST` data for sure will need some `HTTP` service. What I'm asking for is if it's possible to send the data without importing any of the `org.apache.http` packages. All the SO answers and the examples I found on the internet are using this package. And I, for some reason, don't want to use it if this is possible.

Comment: Step through all the code you will need if you have used apache HTTP class and post the data. Then just copy the code that you stepped through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use square's [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library for POST data to server.

Comment: Sorry, but want to use the `AsyncTask` class. And I don't want to download any classes.